# Android android:cacheColorHint issue

Tags: android

I am trying to create a simple `ListView` with shadow to it. My problem is when I scroll the ListView sometimes it's just leave the ListView completely highlighted. Please help me to solve this problem. many thanks.

normally looks like this.
 [image]

when i finished scrolling looks like this

[image]

I have uploaded the sample code [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/QOBNvmef/ListViewExample.html).
http://www.2shared.com/file/QOBNvmef/ListViewExample.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main XML file add this line in list view....

*android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"*

Your main.xml should be--->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip">

    <ListView  
        style="@style/ListView"   android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/ssss"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it. but this will hide the shadow on top and bottom i do not want to hide it

Comment: Try this using custom title bar..........                       https://github.com/thanksmister/CustomTitleBar